# One line of code changed from Pnp to CSOM

Tags: pnp-powershell

I have this line of code made with PnP.

```
(Get-PnPList | ? {$_.Title -like "Stand-By*"} | select Title).count
```

But I need it change too CSOM code.
I don't know how to do that/

Gr. P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client") #| Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime") #| Out-Null
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll"
cls

$username = "login@domain.com"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force

$siteUrl = [string]::Format("https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/zvi/")
$cc = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$cc.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)

$lists = $cc.Web.Lists
$cc.Load($lists);
$cc.ExecuteQuery();
$i = 0
foreach($list in $lists)
{    
    if($list.Title -like "Doc*")
    {
        $i++
    }
}
Write-Host "Count of Standb lists:" $i
```

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: I get an error. How can I search for all list begin with "Standby*)

Comment: $countlist = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Stand-By*")
$Context.Load($countlist);
$Context.ExecuteQuery();
$countlist.ItemCount

Comment: edited sorry, badly read :)

Comment: It gives me the row count of each list. But I need how many lists are there beginning with "Standb*"

Comment: no its filtering by the name -like Standb*, so if you have 30lists/libraries and 5 of them are starting with Standb, you will got only 5 outputs

Comment: ah you mean count of the lists not the lists items got it wait :D

Comment: script edited :) sorry :D